# SQL : Geolocation

Tags: sql, t-sql, geolocation, ssrs-2008, geo

I have a table with vendors and areas they serve: 
-some vendors serve a zip code
-some serve a whole county
-some serve a whole state
I am trying to generate the geolocation for all of them to then use that on an SSRS map.
I was so far able to get the geolocation for the state but not for the other ones using the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD geolocation geography
```

example:

```
  UPDATE myTable SET geolocation = 'POINT(-85.972173  31.809675)' WHERE ZipCode = 36081
```

but that only works for the vendors that have a zipcode.
the other ones have all in the zipcode column.

Could anyone help solve this problem, Thank you in advance.

Comment: `the other ones have all in the zipcode column.`I don't understand this. What info do you have for the other ones who don't have a zip code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other vendor who are handling ewntire state /country, you can add Polygon geolocation..

Check this link out if this helps:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/introduction-to-sql-server-spatial-data/